# How to read an image using imread?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add gui to my deep learning project based on cnn..
So on clicking classify button ,I need to read an image and send the same to the same prediction function for futher processing. Kindly help me here. I have just shared the part of the code.

```py
def sample_prediction(test_im):
    feed_dict_test = {
        x: test_im.reshape(1, img_size_flat),
        y_true: np.array([[2,1,0]])
    }

    test_pred = session.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict=feed_dict_test)
    return classes[test_pred[0]]

def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    
    #image = image.resize((30,30))
    #image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    #image = numpy.array(image)
   
    #cv2.imshow("frame",inputface)
    #inputface = cv2.resize(inputface, (img_size, img_size), cv2.INTER_LINEAR) / 255

    pred =sample_prediction(image)
    sign = classes[pred+1]
    print(sign)

def show_classify_button(file_path):
    classify_b=Button(top,text="Classify X-ray Image",command=lambda: classify(file_path),padx=10,pady=5)
    classify_b.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    classify_b.place(relx=0.79,rely=0.46)
    
    label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign)
```

When I run this,Exception in Tkinter callback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\envs\Pneu Packages\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "cnn_train_test.py", line 489, in <lambda>
    classify_b=Button(top,text="Classify X-ray Image",command=lambda: classify(file_path),padx=10,pady=5)
  File "cnn_train_test.py", line 482, in classify
    pred =sample_prediction(image)
  File "cnn_train_test.py", line 372, in sample_prediction
    x: test_im.reshape(1, img_size_flat),
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: Try uncommenting `image = numpy.array(image)`

Answer (score 0):

You can read, write and process images as Numpy arrays or PIL Images and you can move between the two types as you go. Be aware that OpenCV uses BGR ordering, while PIL and most other packages assume RGB.

---

So, you can read your image into a Numpy array with **OpenCV**:

```
import cv2

# Load a file into a Numpy array - "na" will be BGR order
na = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

And write that Numpy array to disk with **OpenCV** using:

```
import cv2

# Write Numpy array to disk as image - "na" must be BGR order
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', na)
```

---

Or you can use **PIL** to load your image as a **PIL** `Image`:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load a file into a "PIL Image"
pi = Image.open('input.jpg')
```

And write that `Image` to disk with **PIL**:

```
from PIL import Image

# Save PIL Image to disk
pi.save('result.png')
```

---

You can convert a **PIL** `Image` to a Numpy array like this:

```
# Make Numpy array from PIL Image
na = np.array(pi)
```

And convert a Numpy array to a **PIL** `Image` like this:

```
# Make PIL Image from Numpy array
pi = Image.fromarray(na)
```

Bear in mind the channel ordering and potentially use this to re-order the channels:

```
BGRarray = cv2.cvtColor(RGBarray, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

or

```
RGBarray = cv2.cvtColor(BGRarray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: How would you display the cv2 image in tkinter? PIL images are much easier to display on tkinter GUIs (from my experience)

Comment: @TheLizzard I agree that PIL Images are easier to display in `tkinter`. I understood from the OP's code that a Numoy array was required for some sort of Neural Network, since the code seems to be calling Numpy functions like `reshape()` and `resize()`. I will try to improve my answer.